# Selecting service (WMS / WFS) through GeoServer REST API?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, curl, ows

Is it possible to select a service (WMS / WFS) through the Geoserver REST-API?

I know how to add a workspace through the REST-API, like this

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<workspace><name>workspacename</name></workspace>" %resturl%/workspaces
```

But I would like to add a service (WMS or WFS or both) through the REST-API. If this is possible I don't have to go the the webadmin-page the select the service manually. 
Does someone know if this is possible?

Comment: what do you mean select a service? your new layer will show up in both by default.

Comment: If I look in the webadmin at the workspace I added through the REST-API. I don't see a mark at the services WMS and WFS.

Comment: A workspace should contain layers which will show up in the wms and wfs

Comment: If I want the service to be only WMS, I can select that at the workspace. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is asking whether it's possible (or was possible 2014) to configure whether a set of data can be served as a WMS or WFS etc using the GeoServer 'REST' API.

At the time of the question being asked I think the answer was no.

There was a request [GSIP 76 Extend REST API to configure settings and OWS services](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-76---Extend-REST-API-to-configure-settings-and-OWS-services) to add such capability (11 Jun 2014).

The API now provides such capability through the `/services/.../settings` URL pattern.   See the [GeoServer OWS Services documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/services.html) for details

Comment: But how can I use it? I am not understanding reading the documentation. May you tell me?

Comment: @Falcoa : If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question. This isn't a forum. Please say what you are trying to do, what you've already looked, what you tried, and what the results were, plus what you expected to happen instead.