# How to set up a Workspace setting in Geoserver using Curl

Tags: geoserver, curl

I have successfully created a workspace + store + raster layer in Geoserver using Curl in PHP.

If I go back to Geoserver's UI and enter the Workspace that I have just created, the Settings: 'Enable' and any of the 'Services' are UNchecked (empty). I would like to enable them by using Curl.

If you visit:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#

Apparently the only -simplest?- way of creating a workspace in geoserver is by using the XML tags:

`<workspace><name>your name</name></workspace>`

If I try to add new tags to the XML expression above, such as for instance

`<enabled>True</enabled>`

it gives you an error.

`[500] No such field org.geoserver.catalog.impl.WorkspaceInfoImpl.enabled`

So, Have anyone successfully configured those options of the Workspace by using Curl? For instance enabling WMS Services for that workspace?

By the way this post does not help too much:

[Selecting service (WMS / WFS) through GeoServer REST API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82561/is-it-possible-to-select-a-service-wms-wfs-through-the-geoserver-rest-api?rq=1)

Comment: I have got the same problem with a layer object. I' ve solved the problem with a PUT request instead of the POST request used fro the creation of the layer.

Comment: If you're not averse to using Python, I put a workaround [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/244050/3112) which uses Selenium to open a browser and make those changes programatically after you've created the workspace

Answer (score 1):

This looks like missing functionality (probably means it was added after the REST store) - so feel free to open a [Jira ticket](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/introduction/gettinginvolved.html#bug-tracking) noting the issue and then attach a patch or pull request with the fix in.