# How to generate a WMS but not WFS?

Tags: wms, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I am generating geographical services from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database in GeoServer using python, more specifically the gsconfig library.

I am using commands such these demonstrated in this link: https://www.gaiaresources.com.au/geoserver-rest-python/

So far so good. The problem is that when I generate a geographical service I am creating both WMS and WFS. And I just want, in some cases, to generate a WMS but not a WFS.

How can I do this configuration?

Comment: disable the WFS service - I don't think you can do that from REST

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82561/is-it-possible-to-select-a-service-wms-wfs-through-the-geoserver-rest-api

Comment: But how can I disable the WFS for a specific workspace?